# Gold tag badge holder closed a question as a duplicate, community voted to reopen, but then closed again for the same reason?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, dupehammer, vote-to-reopen

Years ago, I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751749) that is now probably one of the top search engine results if you search for anything related to pointer size in C++. It's a 10 year old question which still gets discussion from time to time. Recently, someone asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71870205). A C++ gold tag badge holder decided to close my question as the duplicate (?!). I asked what the deal was, and their reasoning was the other question had better answers. I disputed this politely, explained that the answers on the new question were far too verbose and the concise answers of my question were far better. Plus, the recent discussion on the question still made it relevant (side note, I also wouldn't be surprised if a lot of the upvotes on the new question were a result of people redirected there from my question). The community seemed to agree with me, and it was voted to be reopened. A week later, a different C++ gold tag badge holder closed it again as a duplicate of the same target.

What's the deal here? Why is voting to reopen even an option if the question can be closed again by a single user just disagreeing and closing it for the same reasoning? I get it if it's something that's actually a serious violation of the rules, but closing the original question as a duplicate after the community voted to reopen seems a little silly, no? Especially considering I explained pretty clearly why it was the better of the two questions. It's not a big deal, I'm just looking for some clarification on how the vote-to-reopen should be expected to work.

Comment: The question for context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751749/what-is-the-size-of-a-pointer -- no moderators were involved there. Two different gold badge holders in the C++ tag closed it

Comment: Ah, you're right. I assumed they were mods.

Comment: A small note: Closing a question as duplicate is not a punishment nor a bad thing. It helps linking questions together to make the solutions easier to find

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh no, I certainly don't see it as a punishment. But, the linking of questions definitely makes a little more sense.

Comment: Regardless of which post one may think is best, re-opening one but also leaving the other open is surely incorrect use of the gold badge. Because that implies that they are not duplicates at all, which they are.

Comment: There's also the option to have a mod merge the posts, but I honestly don't think that the answers to the old question were that good. Really good answers might address that having different pointer sizes without extra keywords wasn't the best language design idea to begin with, and in practice this has often been solved with [near and far pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749904/what-is-the-difference-between-far-pointers-and-near-pointers), which the C and C++ committees still fail to acknowledge.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I voted to close your question as a duplicate the first time.

I was following the target question, so I was notified when another user suggested your question as a duplicate. I looked it at, and they are basically the same question, so I chose the one that had better answers as the target. If I had seen your question before there were any good answers on the target, I would have dupe-closed it in the other direction.

In general, the age of a question doesn't matter when deciding which question to close as a duplicate. The idea is to point future readers to the post with the best information, and this sometimes results in older questions being closed as duplicates of newer questions.

Your point about "simple to understand" answers is reasonable. The language-lawyer answers, while being very good, are fairly dense and not really approachable. However, I think there are simple answers on the target as well, and I don't think there's anything missing there that's covered in the answers to your question. In cases where there is useful information in answers to both questions, a merge may be in order, but I don't think this is one of those cases.

About single users voting to close your question unilaterally, that's just something users with a gold [tag-badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836) are allowed to do. They're also allowed to unilaterally reopen questions that are closed as duplicates. The reason the question was closed again was for the same reason I closed it, which is that the target is higher quality. I don't agree with reopening it simply because there are simpler answers on your question, but other users are still welcome to vote to reopen if they feel it's appropriate.

Comment: @MGZero No problem. BTW, It looks like I never responded to your first comment to me (on the linked question). I don't know whether I missed it, was busy, or just forgot to respond, but I should have explained my reasoning at the time. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries, can't expect everyone to be at their machine all day answering questions. We have lives haha.

Comment: Excuse me, that seems unfair. The poster has no control over what answers he receives. He can do his best to post the perfect question, make sure it's original, etc. and, years later, someone posts a duplicate and it's the original question which gets closed?

Comment: Why is it unfair that someone posts an answer several years later, @AlainReve ? There is no SLA's on [so]. It's unfair to assume otherwise.

Comment: :) @Larnu I didn't mean it seems unfair to post an answer several years later. I meant it seems unfair to have a good question closed several years later because of a newer question. How can a question be considered a duplicate of something that didn't exist at the time it was posted? It feels like a bug in the flow-of-control :)

Comment: So you would prefer people pointed to lower quality because the content is older, @AlainReve ? That feels more like a bug to me.

Comment: @Larnu No, but the solution could be to add a link to the original question saying something like "There is also good info about that problem on THIS page". When people browse for an answer, they follow links, don't they?

Comment: *"When people browse for an answer, they follow links, don't they?"* One would hope, so the duplicate feature is a great way to mark that link.

Comment: Yes, it is a great way to mark that link. I'm just saying I think the real duplicate is the second post.

Comment: @AlainReve The point of duplicate closures is to have readers pointed to the better information. It's not an indication that the original question did anything wrong. In fact, your suggestion of "*... but the solution could be to add a link to the original question saying something like ...*" is exactly what the duplicate closure is intended to do (in addition to forcing any new answers to be posted in one place, rather than scattered around multiple places). I understand it can seem unfair to the original question, but that's just an unfortunate by-product of the goal.

Comment: On further inspection, I have to agree with cigien - the newer question has better answers (by far), so I reversed my earlier reversal. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: A good canonical dupe will have both easy to understand as well as in-depth language lawyer answers, as long as all answers are correct.

Comment: As for the content, my opinion as another C++ gold badger is that I support @cigien's decision to close the old post as a dupe to the new one. The new question is more researched and has better answers, with a mix of both in-depth "language lawyer" ones as well as easier ones. And of course these kind of questions tend to attract a lot of trash answers at the bottom, but we have to ignore those for both posts.